# Create ArrayList from Postgresql query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, rowmapper

I have following class:

```
public class Person {

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private List<String> habits;
}
```

I have Postgres query which returns me following result using inner join from 2 tables

```
name | lastname|      habits
--------------------------------------      
John | Smith   | ["walking", "eating"]
```

I am trying to write RowMapper as following:

```
private final RowMapper<Person> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {

 String firstName = rs.getString("name");
 String lastName =  rs.getString("lastName");
}
```

I am not sure how to create List habits from "habits column in my result table"

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: I am not an expert, but to my understanding you get the data from the database as string. As such, you could run your serialized list through a parser (something as simple as 'split' might already do and you'll get your list back.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and working fine. You can try the below code what I have understand from your description.

```
String firstName = rs.getString("name");
String lastName =  rs.getString("lastName");
List<String> list  =  rs.getObject("habits");
```

if you get compilation error, it will work definitly

List stringList = new ArrayList;
List objectList = stringList;// this does compile only if List where subtypes of List
objectList.add(new Object());
String s = stringList.get(0);

it should work.
Let me know if you facing still issue

Comment: Thanks for comment. Not sure, I have compilation error. "Required type List, provided Object"

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer

The code below is working fine

```
String[] habits;
        try {
            habits = objectMapper.readValue(rs.getString("habits"), String[].class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        List<String> habitsList = Arrays.stream(habits).toList();
```